Image of a ratio between polynomials in $\mathbb{C}$
I have the following map:
\begin{equation}
G(s,q) = \dfrac{N(s,q)}{A(s,q)}
\end{equation}
where $s\in\mathbb{C}$ and both $N$ and $A%$ are polynomials in $s$ which depend affinely on the parameter $q$. The degree of $N$ is always less or equal to that of $A$.
Suppose that $q\in\mathbb{P}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathbb{P}$ is a convex polytope defined by a set of vertices $\mathscr{V} = \{\bar{q}_i\}_{i=1}^{Q}$.
Intuitively, given the affine dependence on $q$, the image of $G(s,q)$ should be contained in the complex polytope defined by the vertices $\mathcal{G} = \{G(s,\bar{q}_i)\}_{i=1}^{Q}$.
Any ideas on how to prove (or disprove!) this argument? Many thanks!

What's the connection between the title and the body of your post?

Just changed it to be more general. For any fixed $s$, $G$ is the ratio between two affine maps in $q$, which is what I was aiming for with the linear fractional transformation title.
